# postback __EVENTTARGET ID in Page.Request.Form has $ not _ in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am using the ToolkitScriptManager from the Ajax tool kit and I am having a problem finding my button's ID.

My ID's on my controls come back with $ symbols instead of _ symbols, like the following:

> Grid$ctl06$insertButton

This obviously causes problems when attempting to find the control from the Page.Request.Form keys.  I cannot seem to find the determining factor that would cause this.

Now, I know this is the name and in my source I see that the ID is with the _, so why is the Page.Request.Form showing up with the $ symbol instead?  Anybody encounter this before?

UPDATE: Is it possible that since this button is nested within the Grid that is in the UpdatePanel, it is not found in the PreInit event?  I see many other controls have already been initialized by this point, but this one has not.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, the control IDs have '_' and the control names have '$'.  The form collection is based on name, not on ID which is why you are seeing this behavior.  As a side note, it looks like you are using controls within a databound grid, have you tried to use the grid's event handlers to handle these actions?  Then you wouldn't need to know which row or grid that it came from.  [An example of a grid view event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: I am using a databound grid, however, I am attempting to dynamically create controls based on that button press and the contents of the grid.  So I need to work in the Initiation of the page.
I have done this before in so many ways, but this case has the Page.Request.Form returning the name and then fails to find the Control.

Comment: During the page init, isn't the grid empty, i.e. not databound and with no controls?  I think you may need to move your logic to a different part of the page life cycle.